# Update TextView after changing location on Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, coordinates

I have a problem with my code which should display the latitude and longitude of the current position. I have tried simply setting the text in TextView object, unfortunately, it displays mentioned values just one time (at the beginning). I would like to ask you how can I change this behavior to have "live" coordinates update.

There is my code

```
package com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.PlaceLikelihood;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindCurrentPlaceRequest;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindCurrentPlaceResponse;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap.R.id.coordinates;

/**
 * An activity that displays a map showing the place at the device's current location.
 */
public class MapsActivityCurrentPlace extends AppCompatActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final String TAG = MapsActivityCurrentPlace.class.getSimpleName();
    private GoogleMap map;

    // The entry point to the Places API.
    private PlacesClient placesClient;

    // The entry point to the Fused Location Provider.
    private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;

    // A default location (Sydney, Australia) and default zoom to use when location permission is
    // not granted.
    private final LatLng defaultLocation = new LatLng(-33.8523341, 151.2106085);
    private static final int DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private boolean locationPermissionGranted;

    // The geographical location where the device is currently located. That is, the last-known
    // location retrieved by the Fused Location Provider.
    private Location lastKnownLocation;

    // Keys for storing activity state.
    // [START maps_current_place_state_keys]
    private static final String KEY_CAMERA_POSITION = "camera_position";
    private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
    // [END maps_current_place_state_keys]

    // Used for selecting the current place.
    private static final int M_MAX_ENTRIES = 5;
    private String[] likelyPlaceNames;
    private String[] likelyPlaceAddresses;
    private List[] likelyPlaceAttributions;
    private LatLng[] likelyPlaceLatLngs;

    // [START maps_current_place_on_create]
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        // [START maps_current_place_on_create_save_instance_state]
        // Retrieve location and camera position from saved instance state.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            lastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
        }
        // [END maps_current_place_on_create_save_instance_state]
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // Retrieve the content view that renders the map.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
        // Construct a PlacesClient
        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.MAPS_API_KEY);
        placesClient = Places.createClient(this);

        // Construct a FusedLocationProviderClient.
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        // Build the map.
        // [START maps_current_place_map_fragment]
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        // [END maps_current_place_map_fragment]
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_on_create]

    /**
     * Saves the state of the map when the activity is paused.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_on_save_instance_state]
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (map != null) {
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION, map.getCameraPosition());
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_LOCATION, lastKnownLocation);
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_on_save_instance_state]

    /**
     * Sets up the options menu.
     * @param menu The options menu.
     * @return Boolean.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.current_place_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Handles a click on the menu option to get a place.
     * @param item The menu item to handle.
     * @return Boolean.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_on_options_item_selected]
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.option_get_place) {
            showCurrentPlace();
        }
        return true;
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_on_options_item_selected]

    /**
     * Manipulates the map when it's available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_on_map_ready]
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        this.map = map;

        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // [START map_current_place_set_info_window_adapter]
        // Use a custom info window adapter to handle multiple lines of text in the
        // info window contents.
        this.map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            // Return null here, so that getInfoContents() is called next.
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                // Inflate the layouts for the info window, title and snippet.
                View infoWindow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents,
                        (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.map), false);

                TextView title = infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title);
                title.setText(marker.getTitle());

                TextView snippet = infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
                snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                return infoWindow;
            }
        });
        // [END map_current_place_set_info_window_adapter]

        // Prompt the user for permission.
        getLocationPermission();
        // [END_EXCLUDE]

        // Turn on the My Location layer and the related control on the map.
        updateLocationUI();

        // Get the current location of the device and set the position of the map.
        getDeviceLocation();
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_on_map_ready]

    /**
     * Gets the current location of the device, and positions the map's camera.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_get_device_location]
    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        /*
         * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
         * cases when a location is not available.
         */
        try {
            if (locationPermissionGranted) {
                Task<Location> locationResult = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                            lastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                            if (lastKnownLocation != null) {

                                TextView coordinates = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coordinates);
                                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                        lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                                coordinates.setText(latLng.toString());

                                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                        new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                                lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                    .newLatLngZoom(defaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e)  {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_get_device_location]

    /**
     * Prompts the user for permission to use the device location.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_location_permission]
    private void getLocationPermission() {
        /*
         * Request location permission, so that we can get the location of the
         * device. The result of the permission request is handled by a callback,
         * onRequestPermissionsResult.
         */
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            locationPermissionGranted = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_location_permission]

    /**
     * Handles the result of the request for location permissions.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_on_request_permissions_result]
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        locationPermissionGranted = false;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    locationPermissionGranted = true;
                }
            }
        }
        updateLocationUI();
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_on_request_permissions_result]

    /**
     * Prompts the user to select the current place from a list of likely places, and shows the
     * current place on the map - provided the user has granted location permission.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_show_current_place]
    private void showCurrentPlace() {
        if (map == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (locationPermissionGranted) {
            // Use fields to define the data types to return.
            List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.ADDRESS,
                    Place.Field.LAT_LNG);

            // Use the builder to create a FindCurrentPlaceRequest.
            FindCurrentPlaceRequest request =
                    FindCurrentPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeFields);

            // Get the likely places - that is, the businesses and other points of interest that
            // are the best match for the device's current location.
            @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission") final
            Task<FindCurrentPlaceResponse> placeResult =
                    placesClient.findCurrentPlace(request);
            placeResult.addOnCompleteListener (new OnCompleteListener<FindCurrentPlaceResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<FindCurrentPlaceResponse> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                        FindCurrentPlaceResponse likelyPlaces = task.getResult();

                        // Set the count, handling cases where less than 5 entries are returned.
                        int count;
                        if (likelyPlaces.getPlaceLikelihoods().size() < M_MAX_ENTRIES) {
                            count = likelyPlaces.getPlaceLikelihoods().size();
                        } else {
                            count = M_MAX_ENTRIES;
                        }

                        int i = 0;
                        likelyPlaceNames = new String[count];
                        likelyPlaceAddresses = new String[count];
                        likelyPlaceAttributions = new List[count];
                        likelyPlaceLatLngs = new LatLng[count];

                        for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces.getPlaceLikelihoods()) {
                            // Build a list of likely places to show the user.
                            likelyPlaceNames[i] = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName();
                            likelyPlaceAddresses[i] = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress();
                            likelyPlaceAttributions[i] = placeLikelihood.getPlace()
                                    .getAttributions();
                            likelyPlaceLatLngs[i] = placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng();

                            i++;
                            if (i > (count - 1)) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        // Show a dialog offering the user the list of likely places, and add a
                        // marker at the selected place.
                        MapsActivityCurrentPlace.this.openPlacesDialog();

                    }
                    else {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            // The user has not granted permission.
            Log.i(TAG, "The user did not grant location permission.");

            // Add a default marker, because the user hasn't selected a place.
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .title(getString(R.string.default_info_title))
                    .position(defaultLocation)
                    .snippet(getString(R.string.default_info_snippet)));

            // Prompt the user for permission.
            getLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_show_current_place]

    /**
     * Displays a form allowing the user to select a place from a list of likely places.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_open_places_dialog]
    private void openPlacesDialog() {
        // Ask the user to choose the place where they are now.
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // The "which" argument contains the position of the selected item.
                LatLng markerLatLng = likelyPlaceLatLngs[which];
                String markerSnippet = likelyPlaceAddresses[which];
                if (likelyPlaceAttributions[which] != null) {
                    markerSnippet = markerSnippet + "\n" + likelyPlaceAttributions[which];
                }

                // Add a marker for the selected place, with an info window
                // showing information about that place.
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(likelyPlaceNames[which])
                        .position(markerLatLng)
                        .snippet(markerSnippet));

                // Position the map's camera at the location of the marker.
                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(markerLatLng,
                        DEFAULT_ZOOM));
            }

        };
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_open_places_dialog]

    /**
     * Updates the map's UI settings based on whether the user has granted location permission.
     */
    // [START maps_current_place_update_location_ui]
    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (map == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            if (locationPermissionGranted) {
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            } else {
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
                map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                lastKnownLocation = null;
                getLocationPermission();
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e)  {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    // [END maps_current_place_update_location_ui]
}
```

Especially part with my failed textbox update

```
    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        /*
         * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
         * cases when a location is not available.
         */
        try {
            if (locationPermissionGranted) {
                Task<Location> locationResult = fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                locationResult.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
                            lastKnownLocation = task.getResult();
                            if (lastKnownLocation != null) {

                                TextView coordinates = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coordinates);
                                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                        lastKnownLocation.getLongitude());
                                coordinates.setText(latLng.toString());

                                map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                                        new LatLng(lastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
                                                lastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception: %s", task.getException());
                            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                                    .newLatLngZoom(defaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
                            map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e)  {
            Log.e("Exception: %s", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Look at `FusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates`: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback,%20android.os.Looper).  You get the last location once (and display the text) - you need to keep getting updates and the `requestLocationUpdates` is one way.

Comment: Thank you @Andy for your comment, I'll try